# Code help! I would like to overwite background and hover colour for a section

Tags: html, css

I am trying to duplicate a menu section but want the background and on hover colours to be the opposite. The CSS stylesheet/website was not created by me and I am not used to coding.

This page is VERY MUCH in progress https://www.wildedge.co.uk/archery-academy-session/

but I would like the menu to change colour for the 2 lines, eg

```
.squareboxarchery{background-color:#546734;}
.squareboxarchery:hover{background-color:#425227;}
.squarearcherytitle{color:#ffffff;} 
and
.squarebox{background-color:#425227;}
.squarebox:hover{background-color:#546734;}
.squaretitle{color:#ffffff;}
```

I cant work out how to make it a separate entity...
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "the opposite"? What do you mean by "for the 2 lines"?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the dom, I think that :

the second div.fixed_site layer_wrapper should be moved, now its in the first fixed_site layer_wrapper; its logic that two same structures have to be on the same level.

Once that done, you can easily separate your css by :

```
/* applies to the first line */
div.fixed_site layer_wrapper squarebox {}
```

and

```
/* applies to the second line */
div.fixed_site layer_wrapper + div.fixed_site layer_wrapper squarebox {}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using wordpress theme. and you need to login your CMS and do some selections and save the page. if its not working then you need to add extra css for the page with css property !important to overwrite background colors and text colors, hover colors etc.

which will be look like.

```
      .squareboxarchery{background-color:#425227;!important}
      .squareboxarchery:hover{background-color:#546734;!important}
      .squarearcherytitle{color:#ffffff;!important}
```

and

```
     .squarebox{background-color:#546734;!important}
     .squarebox:hover{background-color:#425227;!important}
     .squaretitle{color:#ffffff;!important}
```

use which one you want from above 2 sets.

Or simply add the the lines into **style.css** which will work for you.

Comment: Heres my code.. How do I make either section have the squareboxarchery css? I've editted the style css and copied the squarebox style and just added "archery" was that the correct thing to do? I am using wordpress and have put ur custom code into the custom css section. 

Thank you so much all for your help! Its a mindfield to me this coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CMS -Content Manager System normally you have to overwrite by using !important after your style. 
But there is also another way to avoid using it !important. Install FileZilla, go to the folder where it is the main.css of your website and change manually the lines of code. And then upload again this file in your website. But be careful, if you did not use to do this, duplicate these files twice for security. If you make a mistake you have always the original on your computer.